# Cannot reproduce Michael Nielsen's neural network results with MNIST handwritten digits data

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, mnist

My question might be relevant to anyone who's trying to follow Michael Nielsen's online book on neural networks and deep learning:

http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/

by following the code to load and learn from MNIST handwritten digits data.

I've downloaded the Python 3 files, available here:

https://github.com/MichalDanielDobrzanski/DeepLearningPython35

Following the book I loaded the MNIST data and segregated it into training/validation/test data sets, created a network with 30 hidden neurons, and used stochastic gradient descent (SGD) to learn from the training data (executed in a Jupyter notebook):

```
import mnist_loader
training_data, validation_data, test_data = mnist_loader.load_data_wrapper()

import network
net = network.Network([784, 30, 10])

net.SGD(training_data, 30, 10, 3.0, test_data=test_data)
```

It took a while to run each epoch but the output was sensible:

```
Epoch 0 : 9101 / 10000
Epoch 1 : 9276 / 10000
...
Epoch 28 : 9480 / 10000
Epoch 29 : 9515 / 10000
```

Again, following the book, I increased the number of hidden neurons to 100 and executed the following:

```
net = network.Network([784, 100, 10])

net.SGD(training_data, 30, 10, 3.0, test_data=test_data)
```

But this time got the following output:

```
Epoch 0 complete
Epoch 1 complete
...
Epoch 28 complete
Epoch 29 complete
```

which ran more or less instantaneously.

I don't understand why it hasn't run as previously (slowly with test results of each epoch printed).

I tried re-running the previous line (with 30 neurons) and got the same odd result (rather than the sort of output I initially saw).

Since I'm a newbie, I wondered if there's something peculiar about the way the values were stored that it didn't like the re-definition of net.  So I tried creating a new variable:

```
net2 = network.Network([784, 100, 10]) 
net2.SGD(training_data, 30, 10, 3.0, test_data=test_data)
```

But got the same result.

I'm not getting an error message. So it's even more difficult to debug since I don't even have a clue as to where it's falling down, nor what key words to search for in case someone has already posted a question like this elsewhere!

And since I've just copied someone else's code verbatim at what is essentially the beginning of the book is rather worrying..

I would greatly appreciate some insight into why I'm not getting what I expect to be getting.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like `test_data` becomes `None` somewhere on the way. This would explain the output and the faster training time. Could you check if `test_data` remains the same over the course of your execution?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @randomwalker ! I'm having to get my head around the way the data was zipped, having issues un-zipping it for some reason, but I'll give it a go.

Comment: OK so I've discovered that if I re-load the data the outputs are properly printed and the code takes longer to run (as expected).  So perhaps it's down to the way Jupyter handles memory - maybe the dataset is taking up a lot of memory and it's freed up after some time so that (as you suggested) the data is lost.